# How to configure Jest spec reporter for Protractor in Angular 8?

Tags: protractor, angular8, e2e-testing, ts-jest

For end-to-end testing in Angular, I would like to try out Protractor with Jest for Angular 8. In the configuration file **protractor.conf.js**, spec reporter of Jasmine is defined by default:

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

/**
 * @type { import("protractor").Config }
 */
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.json')
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

My question is, how can I configure similarly like this, but for Jest?

Comment: Just want to make sure I got the idea right. So you want somehow pull  out the jest native reporter and add it to the protractor?

Comment: @YuriyGerasimovich Yes! That's my purpose

Comment: See [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59455686/11593453). If you found a way to use jest for e2e tests in Angular, I'm also interested...